# How to load mulitple urls into one iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I have a list of urls (lets call them url1.com,url2.com,url3.com). I want to load their contents into an ifram so i can copy them. However, if i create seperate iframes for each url i cannot copy them at one. Is it possible to load multiple urls into one ifram which i can then copy. The urls only contain a string of letters and nothing else.

https://pastebin.com/mQVRPXe4

```
<iframe src="https://url1.com" src = name="targetframe" allowTransparency="false" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
<iframe src="https://url2.com name="targetframe" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
<iframe src="https://url3.com name="targetframe" allowTransparency="true" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" >
    </iframe>
```

Comment: First off, are the websites on the same system as the html you are writing? If they are on someone else's server you will need to worry about cross-origin resource sharing. Secondly, what exactly are you doing with the webpages once they are loaded?

Comment: If you are just trying to put the content of multiple pages onto a single page, I would suggest looking into things like AJAX requests. You can load each page into a string and then write the html response onto your page directly

Comment: @TheCrzyMan could you explain further

Comment: Another option would be to use styling and have the iframes just one after the other

Comment: for ajax, just google "ajax html request"

Comment: thanks could you put that as an answer

Comment: which one? Ajax or just having the iframes styled so it looks like one page?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do a couple of things. Namely, use [ajax requests](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_xmlhttprequest_send.asp) or style the iframes. You can easily remove the border on the iframe with the `frameBorder` attribute.

I know this isn't really the best answer, and I'm not really sure what you are really trying to do here, but I was asked to put this as an answer